# How will close active toggle class if i click on other toggle class or elements in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, toggleclass

When I click on any .show I want to close all .list and open just the one I clicked.

I've tried this, but it's not working as expected.

```js
    $('.show').click(function(){
        $('.list1').toggleClass("displaylist");
    });
    $('.show2').click(function(){
        $('.list2').toggleClass("displaylist");
    });
    $('.show3').click(function(){
        $('.list3').toggleClass("displaylist");
    });
```

```css
    .list1, list2,list3{display:none;}
    .displaylist{display:block;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="show"></li>
    <div class="list1">
        <select>
            <option></option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <li class="show2">list2</li>
    <div class="list2">
        <select>
            <option></option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <li class="show3"></li>
```

Comment: this is very unclear

Comment: code, code, code, code!  If you show us your html structure I bet there will be a way to write this so you only need one click event

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, the simplest way will be to add a class to each li and div that is the same and use jquery's `next()` function

```js
$('.show').click(function(){
  $('.list').hide();
  $(this).next().show();
});
```

```css
.list
{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<li class="show">List 1</li>
<div class="list">
  <select>
    <option></option>
  </select>
</div>

<li class="show">List 2</li>
<div class="list">
  <select>
    <option></option>
  </select>
</div>

<li class="show">List 3</li>
<div class="list">
  <select>
    <option></option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit unclear, but after playing with the code you provided, I think I've figured out what you want.

Is this correct?
https://jsfiddle.net/u5cqLwk3/

HTML

```
<li class="show show1">list1</li>
<div class="list list1">
    <select>
        <option></option>
    </select>
</div>
<li class="show show2">list2</li>
<div class="list list2">
    <select>
        <option></option>
    </select>
</div>
<li class="show show3">list3</li>
<div class="list list3">
    <select>
        <option></option>
    </select>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.list {display: none}
.displaylist{display:block;}
```

JS

```
$('.show').click(function(){
    $('.list').removeClass("displaylist");
});
$('.show1').click(function(){
    $('.list1').addClass("displaylist");
});
$('.show2').click(function(){
    $('.list2').addClass("displaylist");
});
$('.show3').click(function(){
    $('.list3').addClass("displaylist");
});
```